# OpenStack Python Nova API Getting Specific Limit Values?

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I've been using the following code to get the limits:

```
compute_limits = novaClient.limits.get().absolute
for s in compute_limits:
    print s.name + " = " + str(s.value)
```

However I only want specific values from the `limits.get()`, namely `totalRAMUsed` and `maxTotalRAMSize`. There seems to be very little on the internet about using the Python API (mainly all about the CLI). Is there a way to get these specific values to avoid displaying all the limit values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display only one specific value:

```
compute_limits = novaClient.limits.get().absolute
for s in compute_limits:
    if s.name == 'totalRAMUsed':
        print s.name + " = " + str(s.value)
        break
```

`compute_limits` is `generator`, you can't receive only one specific value by limit name. But you can convert `compute_limits` to `dict`. For example:

```
compute_limits = novaClient.limits.get().absolute
l = list(compute_limits)
limits = dict(map(lambda x: (x.name, x.value), l))
print limits['totalRAMUsed']
```

Comment: That makes much more sense why I can't just get one value without the others. Good idea to convert it to a dictionary!